# Show Fancybox on center of control only

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, fancybox

I'm developing a web application based on Asp.Net 4.0. I am using ***Telerik RadScheduler*** control in it.

RadScheduler show images in appointment. I am trying to open those images in zoom mode using **Fancybox v 1.3.4**. By default Fancybox open up in center of page which is nice. And I had able to achieve it.

**Code Snippet -**

```
<script type="text/javascript">       

        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            $("a#hlImgRoom").fancybox({ 'overlayShow': false, 'transitionIn': 'elastic', 'transitionOut': 'elastic' });
        });
    </script>

<asp:HyperLink ID="hlImgRoom" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="noborder">
                         <asp:Image ID="imgRoom" runat="server" Height="50" Width="70" AlternateText='<%# Eval("Text") %>' />
                     </asp:HyperLink>
```

*Url of respective controls had been set from code behind.*

### Question

How one can make Fancybox to open on center of that specific control (*in my case it is Scheduler control*). See image showing Fancybox on Scheduler (*I had managed it to show on control in snapshot*).

[image: Fancybox in Scheduler]

Answer (score 0):

Will this help?:

For example, if you have a structure like this:

```
<asp:parentControl id="your parent control">
    <asp:childControl id="your child control" cssClass="thisControl"></asp:childControl>
</asp:parentControl>
```

Then you only need css for this.

```
.thisControl
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: -100px;
}
```